# Get extension without dot using regex

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I have the regex `(.*)(\.zip|\.tar\.gz)` meaning I have two groups, the name ( first part) and the second one that's the extension.

I want to be able to get the second group either zip, tar, or tar.gz without the ., only the extension name, how I can do that using regex only, I am using Java and I don't want to do any substring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the dot outside the second capturing group.

```
(.*)\.(zip|tar(?:\.gz)?)
```